# JavaScript - Moving a character around using WASD but trouble breaking down movement into simpler functions

Tags: javascript, function

I'm making a puzzle game where the user uses WASD to move a character up, left, down, right respectively. It works fine at the moment but I was wondering if there was a way to break the code down into more intuitive functions. Below is my code:

```
function move(e)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
                if (map[y][x] == "@" || map[y][x] == "+") {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (map[y][x] == "@" || map[y][x] == "+") {
                break;
            }
        }

        var player_x = x;
        var player_y = y;

        if (e.key == 'w') {
            var player_new_x = player_x;
            var player_new_y = player_y - 1;

            if (moveBox(player_new_x, player_new_y, "up") === false) {
                return;
            }

            if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == " " ||
                map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == ".") {

                if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == " ") {
                    map[player_new_y][player_new_x] = "@";
                } else if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == ".") {
                    map[player_new_y][player_new_x] = "+";
                }

                if (map[player_y][player_x] == "@") {
                    map[player_y][player_x] = " ";
                } else if (map[player_y][player_x] == "+") {
                    map[player_y][player_x] = ".";
                }
            }
        } else if (e.key == 's') {
            var player_new_x = player_x;
            var player_new_y = player_y + 1;

            if (moveBox(player_new_x, player_new_y, "down") === false) {
                return;
            }

            if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == " " ||
                map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == ".") {

                if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == " ") {
                    map[player_new_y][player_new_x] = "@";
                } else if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == ".") {
                    map[player_new_y][player_new_x] = "+";
                }

                if (map[player_y][player_x] == "@") {
                    map[player_y][player_x] = " ";
                } else if (map[player_y][player_x] == "+") {
                    map[player_y][player_x] = ".";
                }
            }
        } else if (e.key == 'a') {
            var player_new_x = player_x - 1;
            var player_new_y = player_y;

            if (moveBox(player_new_x, player_new_y, "left") === false) {
                return;
            }

            if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == " " ||
                map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == ".") {

                if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == " ") {
                    map[player_new_y][player_new_x] = "@";
                } else if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == ".") {
                    map[player_new_y][player_new_x] = "+";
                }

                if (map[player_y][player_x] == "@") {
                    map[player_y][player_x] = " ";
                } else if (map[player_y][player_x] == "+") {
                    map[player_y][player_x] = ".";
                }
            }
        } else if (e.key == 'd') {
            var player_new_x = player_x + 1;
            var player_new_y = player_y;

            if (moveBox(player_new_x, player_new_y, "right") === false) {
                return;
            }

            if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == " " ||
                map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == ".") {

                if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == " ") {
                    map[player_new_y][player_new_x] = "@";
                } else if (map[player_new_y][player_new_x] == ".") {
                    map[player_new_y][player_new_x] = "+";
                }

                if (map[player_y][player_x] == "@") {
                    map[player_y][player_x] = " ";
                } else if (map[player_y][player_x] == "+") {
                    map[player_y][player_x] = ".";
                }
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
        render();
        }
```

Is it possible to make four functions, one for each of the movement keys? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) **Yes**, it's possible. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes
It´s possible to do what you want, 4 different functions

But ... you should intercept the events keydown (when the user presses the key) and keyup (when the user releases the key)

As long as the key is "pressed" you do the movement

You can create an object like this

```
let move = { moveH : 0 , moveV :0 }
```

When the keydown event is detected for "a" -> {moveH : -1, moveV :0}

```
"s" -> { moveH :0 , moveV :1 }
"w" -> { moveH :0 , moveV :-1 }
"d" -> { moveH :1 , moveV :0 }
```

When the keyup event is detected .. for any key -> {moveH :0 , moveV:0 }

Meanwhile
apply the move to the object on the screen

something like

```
stuff.position =   { x : stuff.position.x + move.moveH , y: stuff.position.y + move.moveV }
```